# AttributeError: get_tables

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql

What is the problem of this code? Should show a list of tables

```
import pg

con = pg.connect(dbname='xxx', host='xxxx', user='xxx')
pgqueryset = con.get_tables()
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 42, in <module>
    pgqueryset = con.get_tables()()
AttributeError: get_tables
```

[**Docs**](http://www.pygresql.org/pg.html#get-tables-get-list-of-tables-in-connected-database)

```
Parameters:
None
Returns:
list:   all tables in connected database
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgres, but from the docs it looks like `get_tables` is a method for a `DB` object, not a `pgobject` connection object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_tables is on the DB class, which is initialised with the same arguments as connect():

Try:

```
db = pg.DB(dbname='xxx', host='xxxx', user='xxx')
pgqueryset = db.get_tables()
```